# R: From long to wide dataframe with new columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame with 3 individuals with each having 3 observations for each of the three variables A, B, and C.

```
df <-read.table(header=TRUE, text="id A B C
                1 0 1 1
                1 0 0 0
                1 1 1 0
                2 1 0 0
                2 1 0 0
                2 1 1 0
                3 0 1 1
                3 0 0 1
                3 0 0 1")
```

I want to convert it in the following format (removing id and creating new ):

```
df <-read.table(header=TRUE, text="1.A 1.B 1.C 2.A 2.B 2.C 3.A 3.B 3.C
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1")
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Keep in mind that it is generally not recommended to have multiple columns with the same name.

Comment: Hi @Clemsang it kind of works but the numbers seem a bit off. For example, the second observation from the first patient is 0 0 0 and with the solution provided, I get 1 0 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
as.data.frame(t(sapply(split(df[, -1], f = df$id), function(x) t(x))))
```

`split` allows to divide data by `id`.

Comment: thanks @Clemsang, works great! any idea on how to maintain the variable names?

Comment: please try `colnames(result) <- rep(colnames(df)[-1], ncol(df) - 1)`